# Prolog program, what this program should do?

Tags: algorithm, tree, prolog

I don't know Prolog at all, but still I need to understand what this program does. Compiler shows that there're 2 syntax errors, but the main logic of this program should still be understandable.

```
domains
 value=symbol
 level=integer
 ltype1=s(value,level)
 ltype2=tree(value,ltype2,ltype2); void
 list1=ltype1*

predicates
 append(list1,list1,list1)
 totree(ltype2,integer,list1)

clauses
 append([],X,X).
 append([X|T],Y,[X|Z]):-append(T,Y,Z).

 totree(void,_,[]).
 totree(tree(X,Y,Z),N,[s(X,N)|TA]):-
    K=N+1,
    totree(Y,K,TA1),
    totree(Z,K,TA2),
    append(TA1,TA2,TA).

goal
 totree(
    tree(a,tree(b,tree(c,void,void),tree(e,void,void)),tree(d,void,void)),
    1,C),
 write(C),
 totree(W,1,
          [s(a,1),s(b,2),s(c,3),s(e,3),s(d,2)]).
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You haven't said what the errors are. But it looks like you're trying to run a Turbo/PDC/Visual Prolog program in SWI which will not work. Turbo, PDC, and Visual Prolog are non-standard Prolog implementations. The sectioning into `domains`, `predicates`, `clauses`, and `goal` are unique to those implementations. You basically have to get rid of the `domains` and `predicates` section. `clauses` are the predicates that you are trying to define. `goal` should either be written as a predicate or called directly. There are other differences in implementations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the program you can run:

```
append([],X,X).
append([X|T],Y,[X|Z]):-
    append(T,Y,Z).

totree(void,_,[]).
totree(tree(X,Y,Z),N,[s(X,N)|TA]):- 
    K is N+1,
    totree(Y,K,TA1),
    totree(Z,K,TA2),
    append(TA1,TA2,TA).
```

If you run the query

`?-totree(tree(a,tree(b,tree(c,void,void),tree(e,void,void)),tree(d,void,void)),1,C).`

the result will be

`C = [s(a, 1), s(b, 2), s(c, 3), s(e, 3), s(d, 2)]`.

The predicate `totree/3` accepts as input:

- a tree represented as `tree(RootElement,Left,Right)` where `Left` and `Right` are the left and right subtrees,
- a number wich is the level of the tree where you are
- and returns a list wich is the representation of the tree.

Let's analyze the result.

- `s(a,1)`: the element `a` is at the level 1 of the tree, correct because is the root (level 1 because is specified in the query).
- `s(b,2)`: the element `b` is at the level 2 of the tree, correct because `b` is the left child of `a`.
- `s(c,3)`: the element `c` is at the level 3 of the tree, correct because `c` is the left child of `b` and also a leaf.
- and so on...

This is the definiton of `append/3`: `append(List1,List2,List3)` `List3` is the concatenation of `List1` and `List2` (this predicate is already available in some libraries as `lists`.